# Removing and overwriting layer from interface within Plugin

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, ogr

I want to create a shapefile with a QGIS Python plugin. If the same shapefile is already in QGIS Interface, I need to remove it, delete it from the computer, create the new layer and load it.

When I'm trying to delete the data source with `OGR`, `.shx` and `.prj` are well deleted but `.dbf` and `.shp` still exists and I have a permission error:

> PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file
> because it is being used by another process
> "full/path/to/the/layer.shp"`

I also tried `os.remove()` and `os.path.exists()` with the same issue.

```py
import os
import osgeo.ogr as ogr
from qgis.core import QgsProject

# Set up the shapefile driver
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")

# Create the data source
myLayer = "full/path/to/the/layer.shp"

# Delete layer from QGIS interface
for lyr in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values():
    if lyr.name() == "myLayerName":
        QgsProject.instance().removeMapLayer(lyr.id())

# Delete file
if os.path.isfile(myLayer):
    driver.DeleteDataSource(myLayer)
```

If I delete the layer from QGIS Interface directly in the Python console, it works fine: layer disappear from the interface and I can overwrite the file. But it doesn't work similar when I execute it from my plugin's script. It seems like some elements are still in QGIS memory.

What the best way to definitely remove a layer and all his dependencies from QGIS in a plugin script?

I'm using QGIS 3.10.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behaviour seems to be a Python [gotcha](https://gdal.org/api/python_gotchas.html#saving-and-closing-datasets-datasources). The only way i found to deal with it is to check the folder of my Shapefile for files with the same name and create a new file with a suffix if it already exists. If anyone have a better way, I take it.